# Convert SQL to Lambda Expression with one to many relationships

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, lambda

I need to convert the following sql expression to c# lambda syntax:

```
SELECT PatientProfiles.PatientLastName, 
       Visits.VisitId, 
       Visits.VisitDate, 
       Visits.EndVisitDate 
FROM Visits 
INNER JOIN PatientProfiles ON 
               Visits.PatientProfile_PatientId = PatientProfiles.PatientId
```

`PatientProfile_PatientId` is foreign key in Visit table. `Patient -> Visit` has one to many relationship. I need to be able pull all visits from the Visit table along with Patient Name from PatientProfile parent table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using EF Code First :

```
var result = from profile in db.PatientProfile.Include(p => p.Visit)
             from visit in profile.Visits
             select new
                    {
                        profile.PatientLastName,
                        visit.VisitId,
                        visit.VisitDate,
                        visit.EndVisitDate
                    };
```

If returns an anonymous type containing requested data..

Answer (score 1):

Use the syntax for [`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311040.aspx)

```
from visit in Visits
join patientProfile in PatientProfiles
on visit.PatientProfile_PatientId equals patientProfile.PatientId
select new
{
    patientProfile.PatientLastName,
    visit.VisitId,
    visit.VisitDate,
    Visit.EndVisitDate
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have one problem with this syntax. For some reason visit.PatientProfile_PatientId is underlined in red color. It doesn't recognize PatientProfile_PatientId field (since its foreign key of one to many relationship). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention your datasource.  That would prefix your table names.
But the linq join syntax is straight forward.

```
var results = (from v in Visits
               join pp in PatientProfiles on 
                            v.PatientProfile_PatientId equals pp.PatientId
               select new
                        {
                           pp.PatientLastName,
                           v.VisitId,
                           v.Visitdate,
                           v.EndVisitDate
                         })
```